# php -fpm sockets and TCP at same time

Tags: nginx, php

is that possible to use php-fpm to listen sockets and TCP at same time ?
as we are planning to use local nginx to use sockets and remote nginx to use tcp

of not is that possible to use php-fpm socket form remote host ?

Comment: If you'll try you know

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this. But the wiki says you can listen to both ports and unix sockets  with `listen_address`.

http://php-fpm.org/wiki/Configuration_File